# How to change view based on unique Id in android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

I have three different layouts. I need to show in an adapter view based on the unique Identifier.I categorized that three different views using switch case.But It was picking only one layout view and displaying on the emulator when I run the code.The view should be changed based on the unique Id.

```
public class PromotionsFeedActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{


    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
    public static ArrayList<String> Id=new ArrayList<String> ();

    public static ArrayList<String> Titles = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> Title2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> Categorie = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> videoURL=new ArrayList<String> ();
    public static ArrayList<String> Pictures=new ArrayList <String> ();

    public static ArrayList<String> PartnerId=new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> BuyUrl;



    public static ArrayAdapter<String> pfAdapter;
    ListView show;
    VideoView videoView;
    ImageView btnWatchVideo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_promotions_feed);

//        Id=new ArrayList<String>();
//        Titles=new ArrayList<String> ();
//        Title2=new ArrayList<String> ();
//        Categorie=new ArrayList<String> ();
//        videoURL=new ArrayList<String> ();
//        Pictures=new ArrayList<String> ();
//        PartnerId=new ArrayList<String> ();
//        BuyUrl=new ArrayList<String> ();

        btnWatchVideo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnWatchVideo);
        btnWatchVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(PromotionsFeedActivity.this,MediaActivity.class));
            }
        });

        for(int i=0; i < PartnerId.size(); i++){
          Log.i("PartnerIds",(PromotionsFeedActivity.PartnerId.get(i)));
            Log.i("PartnerSize",String.valueOf(PartnerId.size()));
            String id = PromotionsFeedActivity.PartnerId.get(i);

            switch(id){

                case "5": Log.i("Partner:",id);
                    Log.i("PartnerSize",String.valueOf(PartnerId.size()));
                    show = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_pf);
                    pfAdapter = new PromotionFeedAdapter(PromotionsFeedActivity.this, R.layout.livefeed_adapter, Title2);
                    pfAdapter = new PromotionFeedAdapter(PromotionsFeedActivity.this, R.layout.livefeed_adapter, Titles);
                    showData(pfAdapter);
                    break;
                case "3": Log.i("Partner:",id);
                    Log.i("PartnerSize",String.valueOf(PartnerId.size()));
                    show = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_pf);
                    pfAdapter = new PromotionFeedAdapter(PromotionsFeedActivity.this, R.layout.livefeed_adapter_groupon, Title2);
                    pfAdapter = new PromotionFeedAdapter(PromotionsFeedActivity.this, R.layout.livefeed_adapter_groupon, Titles);
                    showData(pfAdapter);
                    break;
                case "null":Log.i("Partner:",id);
                    Log.i("PartnerSize",String.valueOf(PartnerId.size()));
                    show = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_pf);
                    pfAdapter = new PromotionFeedAdapter(PromotionsFeedActivity.this, R.layout.livefeed_adapter_news, Title2);
                    pfAdapter = new PromotionFeedAdapter(PromotionsFeedActivity.this, R.layout.livefeed_adapter_news, Titles);
                    showData(pfAdapter);
                    break;
            }
            Log.i("Last",id);
        }
    }
    public void showData(ArrayAdapter<String> adapter){
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        show.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

PromotionFeedAdapter.java

```
public class PromotionFeedAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    public int layout;
    Button getCal;
    public static String MY_PREFS_NAME="my_prefs";

    public PromotionFeedAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        layout=resource;
    }
    Context mContext;

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent){
        ViewHolder2 mainViewHolder=null;
        mContext = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView= inflater.inflate(layout,parent,false );
        final ViewHolder2 viewHolder=new ViewHolder2();

        viewHolder.title=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pf_title);
        viewHolder.title2=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pf_title2);
        viewHolder.category=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pf_category);
        viewHolder.picture=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pf_main_pic);
        viewHolder.title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getBusinessProfile();
            }
        });
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        mainViewHolder=(ViewHolder2)convertView.getTag();
        mainViewHolder.title.setText(getItem(position));
        String title2,picUrl,category;
        picUrl=PromotionsFeedActivity.Pictures.get(position);
        category=PromotionsFeedActivity.Categorie.get(position);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        URL newurl = null;
        try {
            newurl = new URL(picUrl);
            Picasso.with(getContext()).load(picUrl).into(viewHolder.picture);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return convertView;
    }


    public class ViewHolder2 {
        TextView id;
        TextView title;
        TextView title2;
        ImageView picture;
        TextView category;
    }
```

activity_promotion_feed.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.arunmannuru.arun.PromotionsFeedActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/farbinder_logo" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/pin"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My Location"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnWatchVideo"
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/watch_video_dark"
            android:layout_weight="0.16" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="415dp"
        android:id="@+id/lv_pf">

    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:padding="@dimen/bottom_navigation_padding">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/specials"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/specials"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="ShowSpecials"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/calendar"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/calendar"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="ShowCalendar"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/search"
            android:onClick="ShowSearch"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/search"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btnComunity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/community"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/community"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="ShowCommunity"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/profile"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/profile"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="ShowProfile"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

livefeed_adapter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="380dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/img_frame_1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/boarder">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/special_icon"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="330dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="$80 Toward Gourmet Stackhouse"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/pf_title"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="370dp"
            android:layout_height="220dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/pf_main_pic"
            android:src="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:src="@drawable/special_tag"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/pf_main_pic"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/pf_main_pic" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Artistic Expert Picture Framing"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Retail"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

livefeed_adapter_groupon.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="380dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/img_frame_1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/boarder">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/special_icon"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="330dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="$80 Toward Gourmet Stackhouse"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/pf_title"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="370dp"
            android:layout_height="220dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/pf_main_pic"
            android:src="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:src="@drawable/special_tag"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/pf_main_pic"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/pf_main_pic" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/powered_by_groupon"
            android:layout_marginTop="173dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="240dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Artistic Expert Picture Framing"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Retail"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post complete code rather than unformatted snippets.

Comment: I just updated the code.. You can see the PromotionFeedActivity.java ,PromotionFeedAdapter.java , live_feed_adapter.xml,live_feed_groupon.xml @Ben

Comment: Then what are you expecting? In my mind this code will lead to the listview showing the sub-view according to the last `PartenerId`.

Comment: I see. Are you trying to show mixed sub-views simultaneously?

Comment: yup.. I want to show three different views based on the PartnerId. simultaneously.. @Ben

Comment: I have like 300 listings. Which I have stored in arraylist(PartnerId). And I am categorizing the view based on the id..there are three different id's(3,5,null).. Based on that id I have to show the view.@Ben

Answer (score 0):

Delete `int resource` from `PromotionFeedAdapter::PromotionFeedAdapter`.

Delete All Code below `setContentView(R.layout.activity_promotions_feed);` in `onCreate` of you `Activity`, and replace them with

```
pfAdapter = new PromotionFeedAdapter(PromotionsFeedActivity.this, Title2);
showData(pfAdapter);
```

Then modify your adapter.

in `getView`:

```
switch(PromotionsFeedActivity.PartnerId.get(position)){
    case "5":layout=R.layout.livefeed_adapter;break;
    case "3":layout=R.layout.livefeed_adapter_groupon;break;
    case "null":layout=R.layout.livefeed_adapter_news;break;
}
convertView= inflater.inflate(layout,parent,false );
```

, instead of switching in Activity.

Try using `Map` for cleaner code. I'm hand-writing and d**n Java is too long to use `Map`.

Comment: This was working.. But the position returns only 1 and 0. But if we iterate through the PartnerId list.It contains more number of id's.Each id might be 3,5 or null.If we take that scenario.It will returns wrong format of display. @Ben

Comment: @user1918566 Updated

Comment: If I delete rest of the code.And replace with showData(pfAdapter) which activity it will choose among three layouts.There is another issue. @Ben

Comment: @user1918566 I forgot to point out that you should delete the `layout` parameter in the constructor of the adapter

Comment: So In promotinfeedadapter I need to put only context in the constructor.??

Comment: @user1918566 Yes.